# Horizontal Legend in PieChart achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine

I have implemented a piechart using achartengine. The legend of the Pie chart is being displayed at the bottom of the chart in a single line as shown below:

oA oB oC oD

But I want the legend to be displayed in multiple lines with one label per line as below:

o A

o B

o C

o D

Any help would be appreciable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, legends cannot be moved in Achartengine API. However, in order to move it to another location transparent frameLayout can be used.
Refer to following posts for discussions. Hope they will help.

[how to display legend on right side of piechart in achartengine android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553067/how-to-display-legend-on-right-side-of-piechart-in-achartengine-android?rq=1)

[How to set different values for Legend and Labels in piechart While I am using Chart Engine in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13657432/how-to-set-different-values-for-legend-and-labels-in-piechart-while-i-am-using-c)

[achartengine Legend issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949746/achartengine-legend-issue)

Comment: Thanks Yasir! Some sample codes for doing it using transparent layout would be helpful!